duplicate a form with all data , attachments ,subforms's data
Hi i am working on a ms file for identification cart of the equipment, but it dose not really matter
anyway i want to have bottom to duplicate an equipment form with all of the data and attachments and sub forms
thank you for helping me and sorry i cant wright well in english
here is my code, its work for textboxes and combo boxes but i don't no what should i do with attachments fields, i am not working on sub forms yet
Private Sub duplicate_bottom_Click()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
rst.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark

DoCmd.Close acForm, "main-inst-id-frm", acSaveYes
DoCmd.OpenForm "main-inst-id-frm", acNormal, , , acFormAdd, acWindowNormal

With Forms![main-inst-id-frm]

![feild-name].Value = rst![feild-name].Value
![subgroup1-name].Value = rst![subgroup1-name].Value
![group-code].Value = rst![group-code].Value
![w-discription].Value = rst![w-discription].Value
![type].Value = rst![type].Value
![n-capicity].Value = rst![n-capicity].Value
![life_time].Value = rst![life_time].Value
![life_time_unit].Value = rst![life_time_unit].Value
![water-usage].Value = rst![water-usage].Value
![power-usage].Value = rst![power-usage].Value
![power-type].Value = rst![power-type].Value
![gasusage].Value = rst![gasusage].Value
![mass].Value = rst![mass].Value
![frame-material].Value = rst![frame-material].Value
![dimention].Value = rst![dimention].Value
![price].Value = rst![price].Value
![sellername].Value = rst![sellername].Value
![sellerphone1].Value = rst![sellerphone1].Value
![buildername].Value = rst![buildername].Value
![sellerphone2].Value = rst![sellerphone2].Value
![agency].Value = rst![agency].Value
![warranty-duration].Value = rst![warranty-duration].Value
![agency-phone].Value = rst![agency-phone].Value
![agency-address].Value = rst![agency-address].Value

End With
End Sub



You can do this using the RecordsetClone - see full code here:
Duplicate records in main form , subform and subsubform
It should copy attachment fields as well, as described here:
Access 2010 accdb file bloating when I copy attachment field
but I don't use those, so it is not tested.
To copy attachment fields, you must use the Recordset2 as shown here:
Copy fields which consist of Attachments from single record to another table?

hi thank you i use this code even before i try to code myself , this code work nice but the problem is attachments

I located an example. See inserted link, please.
